# Cannot connect MBP to Dell U2417H monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook-pro, usb-c

I have contacted Apple as well as Dell Support multiple times on this issue. I also have looked at Apple/Dell guides to connecting monitors of which none work.

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro and am trying to do a dual monitor setup. One of these 2 monitors is a LG one, which I am using a USBC to HDMI cable. This works like a charm.

However, the second monitor is a Dell U2417H and no matter what I do it does not connect. The funny thing that it used to connect just like a month ago and suddenly it stopped working. (This means that I must have accidentally changed some setting) I have a USBC to PD+HD(4K)+VGA+Audio+USB 3.0 Converter adapter ([https://www.amazon.com/Charging-Converter-Compatible-Chromebook-Mainstream/dp/B07H4HWGWC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H4HWGWC)). I have an HDMI to HDMI cable which i just recently bought from Apple(https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKQ32ZM/A/belkin-ultrahd-4k-hdmi-cable-2m?afid=p238%7Cssy7IWqdQ-dc_mtid_1870765e38482_pcrid_246387003261_pgrid_49565832687_&cid=aos-us-kwgo-pla-btb-3pp--slid---product-HKQ32ZM/A). I used to have another HDMI to HDMI cable, but I thought maybe the HDMI cable was spoiled but that was not the case.

From what I see on the Displays settings, the MBP is recognizing the Dell Monitor (Its just not showing anything on the monitor) If i go to displays, I see 3 blue rectangles which means it is recognizing the Dell monitor (the three rectangles represent the actual MBP, the LG monitor, and of course the Del monitor).

I also do not think the 5 in 1 adapter is spoiled because charging the Mac Book Pro using the USB-C port on the adapter works (and so does the USB).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue, as I have been trying to fix this for a long time. I think this is a minor fix because given that it worked before (using the same setup), I might have accidentally changed something in the settings.